# Why don't relational databases support aggregate function indexing?

Tags: database, indexing, data-structures, aggregate-functions

I've been learning about how relational databases work and how to use them. As far as I've been able to tell, none of the major ones allow you to efficiently index aggregate functions, only scalar ones. Why is this?

For instance, let's say you're tracking a financial account. You have lots of transactions and you want to know what the account balance is. With current implementations, you are forced to either run a full table query to aggregate a sum of all transactions or store redundant derived data, along with all the headaches this brings.

Since indices are basically just B-trees, why can't the nodes store partial sums for all of their children? That way, the database can construct the sum for any contiguous index region in logarithmic time. I'm not sure if this would work for any aggregate function, but the most usual ones like min, max, sum, count and average are trivial to divide and conquer this way.

So am I missing some subtle problems with this approach? Or is there another reason why this concept doesn't get implemented? Because it doesn't sound that hard.

Comment: Though this is theoretically possible,in practice it would be worthless. Indexes essesntialy consist of (values for) key-fields + tuple-pointers, which are rather immutable, so the index does not need to change much. Adding other attibutes (such as aggregates) to the index *table* would cause it to be changed very often. Adding one cent to one record of the balance table would cause all  the index-pages upto the root to be changed. Now just add add transactions to that picture ... Note: for COUNT() your proposal is actually possible (practically: for free) , and often implemented...min() max()

Comment: @wildplasser Every single insert, update or delete operation might change the tree all the way up to the root already anyway. Count also requires you to change the tree all the way to the root for every operation so I don't see the difference. Proposed approach would eliminate the need to keep a balance table, which is not only an additional step when adding a transaction, but changing one transaction a 1000 records ago forces you to change all the 999 balances before it. And you need to rely on the DB users to always do these things consistently and atomically.